# How to flatten mixed dimensional array into a two dimensional list?

Tags: python, list, flatten

I know there are many posts on how I can flatten a two-dimensional list but this one is a bit different because it's a mix of two dimensional and three-dimensional list :

```
items = [[255, 204, 204], ..., [255, 179, 179], [[250, 250, 250], ..., [220, 220, 220]]]
```

I'd like this list to be two dimentional only :

```
items = [[255, 204, 204], ..., [255, 179, 179], [250, 250, 250], ..., [220, 220, 220]]
```

---

I tried to use list comprehension but it doesn't flatten the list correctly :

```
flat_list = [item for items in l for item in items]
```

What would be the best way of flattening mixed dimensional array into a two-dimensional one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```
def flatten(items):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item[0], list):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item
```

Demo:

```
>>> items = [[255, 204, 204], [255, 179, 179], [['250, 250, 250'], ['220, 220, 220']]]
>>> list(flatten(items))
[[255, 204, 204], [255, 179, 179], ['250, 250, 250'], ['220, 220, 220']]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
old_list = [[255, 204, 204], [255, 179, 179], [['250, 250, 250'], ['220, 220, 220']]]                                                                                                         
new_list = []  
for i in old_list:
    if isinstance(i[0], list):
        for j in i:
            new_list.append(j)
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
print new_list
```

The output is:

```
[[255, 204, 204], [255, 179, 179], ['250, 250, 250'], ['220, 220, 220']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain

items = [[255, 204, 204], [255, 179, 179], [['250, 250, 250'], ['220, 220, 220']]]

flat_list = list(chain.from_iterable(lst if isinstance(lst[0], list) else [lst] for lst in items))

print(flat_list)
>>> [[255, 204, 204], [255, 179, 179], ['250, 250, 250'], ['220, 220, 220']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def tree2matrix(T):
  if T == []:
    return []
  elif type(T) is not list:
    return [[T]]
  elif type(T[0]) is not list:
    return [T]
  else:
    return tree2matrix(T[0]) + tree2matrix(T[1:])

X = [[255, 204, 204], [255, 179, 179], [['250, 250, 250'], ['220, 220, 220']]]
print(tree2matrix(X))
```